# Windows 8 / 8.1 / 8.1 Update 1 Bluetooth File Transfer

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth

My laptop came with Windows 8 pre-installed. I've since updated it to Windows 8.1, and recently, 8.1 update 1.

For an OS which focused on more mobile tech, I have to say, it sure made BlueTooth File transfers a PITA, especially compared to Windows 7.

Here's my BlueTooth Icon on the systray. Notice the lack of Send / Receive File Options.

[image]

And here's my BlueTooth Settings:

[image]

I don't see anything out of the ordinary. I'm aware that I can type `fsquirt` in command prompt to bring up the original File Transfer Dialog, but really, Windows 8?

Is there an easier way to do this? Did I miss something?

Comment: There reason the option is missing is likely because you have no devices connected

Comment: You may also have Bluetooth option in "Send To" menu for sending.

Comment: @tumchaaditya, there is an option for that. But, how do I send files from my phone? Without the send / receive dialog box, it automatically denies any incoming connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the ambiguity of your question, I can only guess what the problem is. More research and editing would be required to achieve a definite answer.

The lack of Send/Receive File options is, as Ramhound said, probably due to you not having any devices connected. I recommend checking the connectivity of the device you're trying to transfer files to.

If your bluetooth devices are connected, [your drivers may be out of date](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/cfe4ca18-25cb-47d1-aa1b-22672d09a758/windows-8-cannot-sendreceive-files-via-bluetooth-why).

As (I'm guessing) you know, those options exist, and they look like this:

[image]

[Source](http://www.informatives.net/how-to-use-bluetooth-on-windows-8/)

I provided that image because I'm unsure if you have ever been able to successfully transfer files via Bluetooth, and if anything has changed in your setup since then.

Good luck!

Comment: Here's what's happening: I open BlueTooth on both my phone, and my laptop. My phone tells me I'm connected to my laptop. My laptop is telling me I'm connected to my phone. Those options up there, still aren't visible, even after updating my driver.